# Question about Sylow's Theorem/Conjugation of the set of conjugates of P

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, sylow-theory

I'm trying to understand a proof of the 2nd and 3rd parts of Sylow's Theorem. In some preliminary work, my book establishes that $P$ is a Sylow p-subgroup of $G$.

Then it defines $\{P_1,P_2,...,P_r\}=S$

to be the set of all conjugates of $P$, i.e. $S=\{gPg^{-1} | g \in G\}$.

Then, Let $Q$ be any p-subgroup of $G$. Then, by definition of $S$, $G$ acts by conjugation on $S$.

My first question is this: I understand what it means for a group to act by conjugation on itself. We have $g.a = gag^{-1}$ where $a,g \in G$. However, in this case, $S$ is a set whose elements are also sets. So then, if $s \in S$ then $g.s$ looks like $gsg^{-1}$ but this doesn't actually make sense, since $s$ is not actually an element in $G$ but a set of elements in $G$ so it's unclear to me what the operation looks like. Is it reasonable to assume that I'm supposed to use the group operation iteratively here? I.e. $g.s = \{gs_0g^{-1} | s_0 \in s\}$?

My next question is about orbits. My book states that $S = O_1 \cup O_2 \cup ... \cup O_s$ where $O_i$ is one of the orbits of $G$ on $S$ which I believe. It then goes on to say that $r = |O_1| + ... + |O_s|$ where $r$ is the number of conjugates used earlier. I don't know why this would be true.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think we should consider the action of **Q** on S, instead of G on S. This is because G acts transitively on S, i.e., the action of G has only one orbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S$ is a set of subsets.  You can conjugate a subset:
$$gXg^{-1} = \{gxg^{-1} \mid x \in X\}$$
So the action on $S$ is by conjugation of the subsets.  If $gPg^{-1}$ is a conjugate then the action of $h$ sends $gPg^{-1}$ to $hgPg^{-1}h^{-1} = (hg)P(hg)^{-1}$ which is another conjugate of $P$.

As for why $r$ is the sum of the sizes of the orbits.  This is because the orbits partition $S$.  Every conjugate in $S$ is in exactly one orbit and every orbit contains only elements of $S$.  So counting all the elements in $S$ is the same as counting all the elements in all the orbits.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up quite a bit. As for the first part, that's what I suspected but I couldn't find a solid definition. As for the second part, I think I was still thinking of the oribts of $S$ as elements of $G$ rather than elements of $S$ for some reason. Either way, I understand now.